# What is this 4 pin connector called?

Tags: connector, identification

[image]

I tried connecting the one on the left with the 4 pin fan connectors on my computer PSU, but they are not compatible.

Comment: Is that by any chance attached to an LED strip?

Comment: @pjc50 That would be my guess too - the wire colors are the R/G/B and ground, for typical RGB LED strips I have seen.

Comment: Your fan has +. gnd, pwm and rpm(sense). Are you sure it looks exactly like that, because that is not one of the common fan connectors.

Comment: It is indeed a RGB LED strip. I only tested to see if it was the same connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flat prongs make it look exactly like a JST (Japan Solderless Terminal Mfg. Co.) [SM connector](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/JSTSM.pdf) (Datasheet)

See: http://www.adafruit.com/products/578

Comment: I googled "JST SM" to see the connector from a different angle and sure enough, it is the same connector! Thank you very much.